# Queues filtering in Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

in previous solution it was possible to listen for messages using filter like:

```
@StreamListener(target = Sink.INPUT, condition = "headers['header_name'].equals('header_value')")
```

How can I achieve this in new approach with Consumers?